# Carousel with variable amount of paragraph

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

So guys, somehow I need to have each paragraph of HTML added to carrel using bootstrap.

I tried it:

```
var paragrafos = html.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].parentElement.innerHTML
var qtdParagrafos = html.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].parentElement.childElementCount;
for(let i=0; i < qtdParagrafos; i++)
    <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <p>document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i]</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div for each paragraph and append it to the carousel. Something like this:

```
var paragrafos = document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].parentElement.innerHTML
var qtdParagrafos = document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].parentElement.childElementCount;
for(let i=0; i < qtdParagrafos; i++) {
  let item = document.createElement('div');
  item.setAttribute('class', 'item');
  item.innerHTML = `
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ${document.getElementsByTagName("P")[i].innerHTML}
      </div>
    `;
  carousel.appendChild(item);
}
```

Comment: @leon Can you mark this answer as correct so other know this question is solved?